# Где можно найти уязвимости для Joomla?

Tags: cms, joomla, уязвимости

**Здравствуйте**

Я бы хотел найти список уязвимостей **Joomla** для проверки моего сайта на уязвимости, где можно было бы их найти? Лазил по разным форумам но нигде ясного ответа не нашел.

**Пример уязвимости типа:**

http://server/index.php?option=com_picsell&controller=prevsell&task=dwnfree&dflink=../../../configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, обычно уязвимости ищут на https://nvd.nist.gov/ или https://cve.mitre.org/

Там есть поиск, и по Joomla находится довольно много CVE-шек.

А дальше - уже Ваш опыт должен подсказать, как их натравить на ваш сайт.

Но, по моему, обычно при таких задачах используют  готовые сканеры, вроде Nessus. Он, правда, далеко не бесплатен, но можно взять его "домашнюю" версию, которую, вроде бы, можно применять именно "дома" - там лицензию надо читать, но сммысл вроде бы именно такой.

Или - можно использовать [Nikto](https://cirt.net/nikto2) - готовый сканнер web - уязвимостей

Comment: Спасибо вам что ответили на мой вопро, я искал уязвимости на этих форумах, в большинстве случаев мне помог форум exploit-db.com, но хотелось бы еще больше найти их, для своей программы, мне они нужны в виде таких ссылок как в примере

Comment: спасибо за  exploit-db.com, тоже полезная ссылка